# Dovecot pw generation mismatch

Tags: dovecot

According to [Dovecot's wiki](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes), a SHA256 scheme is the sha256 sum of the password stored in base64.

```
$ doveadm pw -s SHA256 -p "test"
{SHA256}n4bQgYhMfWWaL+qgxVrQFaO/TxsrC4Is0V1sFbDwCgg=
```

but it does not match the output of this command :

```
$ echo -n "test" | sha256sum | awk '{ print $1 }' | base64
OWY4NmQwODE4ODRjN2Q2NTlhMmZlYWEwYzU1YWQwMTVhM2JmNGYxYjJiMGI4MjJjZDE1ZDZjMTVi
MGYwMGEwOAo=
```

Why is it different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. The output of

```
$ echo -n "test" | sha256sum
```

is the hex representation of the hash. `sha256sum` does not have an option for raw (binary) output. This command works :

```
$ echo -n "test" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | base64
```